# how do I get images to flow as they do on google photos album view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I find it extremely difficult to believe the megabytes of css and javascript are required.

I have written a python program to read a yaml file with images for thumbnails and links to my google photo albums because they did away with picasaweb.google.com but kept all the albums.

I would be content to have four images per line scaling by %.  I can't even figure out why these images are stacked vertically and offset.

It would be nice to have this responsive and show different number of album covers depending on width, but scaling is fine.

```html
   <html>
       <head>
           Why the indent
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Why the indent</h1>
       <h2>Nepal</h2>
    
       <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
           <figure>
               <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg"
                   style="width:20%">
               <figcaption>The lake</figcaption
           </figure>
       </a>
    
       <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
           <figure>
               <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg"
                   style="width:20%">
               <figcaption>Chitwan, wild tigers and elephants</figcaption
           </figure>
       </a>
    
       <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
           <figure>
               <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg"
                   style="width:20%">
               <figcaption>Elephant Abuse</figcaption
           </figure>
       </a>
    </body>
```

Comment: You didn't close `<figcaption>`. Are you trying to do something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRBjGr

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't indent:

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't indent:

https://justpaste.it/18uut

Comment: What do you mean it odesn't indent? Where are you talking about wanting an indent? I don't see that in your description. Do you have a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Michael, your example was **exactly what I was looking for**. But see the pasteit link above, and it doesn't show the images on the same line as  your example and I can't figure it out.

Cool site, BTW.

Comment: Here I fixed the first row... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owmywz?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, now I get an H2 break for each country.

Looks like there is one answer, not yours so there is nothing to accept.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... is that what you're going for? Do you want me to submit it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `figcaption`s, then you can use `display: flex` on an element that wraps the `a`'s you want in a row, and set the `a`'s to `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1 0 0` for short so they fill the available width of the row.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex > a {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Why the indent</h1>
<h2>Nepal</h2>
<div class="flex">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
      <figcaption>The lake</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
      <figcaption>Chitwan, wild tigers and elephants</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg">
      <figcaption>Elephant Abuse</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure is an element that has `display: block` property - so it fit one at each line. Try switching to `div` with `h2` instead - that givers you more flexibility and better code understanding for web browsers and SEO.

Btw. you're not even closing `</figcaption` in snippet above.

Comment: Thanks, I fix the </figcaption> used <div><a ...></a><div>

But I still get one picture per line.

Comment: By default div is displayed and block, you must style as `display: inline-block;`